# blank page is displaying in azurewebsites when deployed from github source. It is a nodejs webapp

Tags: node.js, azure, github, azure-web-app-service

I just deployed the code from github to azure.
It is a nodejs web app.
In azure, I'm using app services for this.

Also, I added the code for port in /bin/www

```
var port = process.env.port || 8080; // 8080 for local or whatever number u want
var listener = app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Listening on port ' + port); 
});
```

Still, webpage is not showing up in https://{appname}.azurewebsites.net

Here is the deployment log

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling node.js deployment.
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
Copying file: 'package.json'
Using start-up script bin/www from package.json.
Generated web.config.
The package.json file does not specify node.js engine version constraints.
The node.js application will run with the default node.js version 4.2.3.
Selected npm version 3.5.1
{github-reponame}@0.0.0 D:\home\site\wwwroot
├── lodash@4.4.0 
└── underscore@1.7.0 

Finished successfully.
```

For Justin Pattern's comment... 
In scm, the structure of files, appear to be ok.

I did check the deployment log and the deployment is successful but the page is not displaying.

In scm kudu, the structure of the files appear to be ok. Still, only a blank page shows up when clicked on https://{appname}.azurewebsites.net

Hi Gary-Liu MSFT,
web.config is present in the root.
This is how the web.config looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="bin/www" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^bin/www\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="bin/www"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Update:**
July 24 - 11:05 p.m. EST -- looks like there is some clue to fix this... but now sure how..
Adding more info from the log file: 
The log shows "No element in the source document matches... "

```
2016-07-25T03:03:26 Start 'websitelogs' site extension transform
2016-07-25T03:03:26 :(6,10), No element in the source document matches '/configuration/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='~1{appname}']/application[@path='/websitelogs']'
2016-07-25T03:03:26 Not executing Remove (transform line 6, 68)
2016-07-25T03:03:26 StartSection Executing Insert (transform line 7, 65)
2016-07-25T03:03:26 on /configuration/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='~1{appname}']/application
2016-07-25T03:03:26 Applying to 'site' element (no source line info)
```

**Update** ***Jul 25, 1:25 PM EST***
For Gary-Liu MSFT's comment:
I tried commenting the "port" lines in github and redeployed it and it still azure shows only a blank page when accessed via https://{appname}.azurewebsites.net or http:{appname}.azurewebsites.net

From the application log...

2016-07-25T16:41:15 PID[15128] Warning The configured default provider 'MicrosoftAccount' was ignored
because it is not enabled. An alternate provider will be chosen arbitrarily.
2016-07-25T16:41:15 PID[15128] Information Sending response: 401.71 Unauthorized

the website still shows a blank page ....when accessed via http://{appname}.azurewebsites.net or https://{appname}.azurewebsites.net

the code was deployed via github repo. The website works fine without azure.
It just shows a blank page after deploying to azure web app...

**Update:** 
***July 25, 1:39pm EST***
**Thanks Gary-Liu MSFT**
**Resolved! Thanks!** 
Commenting the port lines helped! Thanks a lot! It is working now! Thanks!
 In addition... It is because , in azure, for this web app, I had enabled the authentication/authorization  to outlook acct. Switched it off and now no more blank page! The site works fine now! The reason , I enabled it to outlook acct was...i was hoping that it would prompt for outlook login! Thanks for your help! The site is up and running in azure now!

Comment: Have you used the SCM/Kudu interface to check the structure of the files that were deployed? There should also be a deployment log for the App Service within the portal. Kudu can be found by going to https://{site name}.scm.azurewebsites.net Also, this video walks through setting up what you are trying to do: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/create-a-nodejs-site-deploy-from-github/

Comment: edited above post to include this scm / kudu / deployment log info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you check whether you have a `web.config` file on the root directory of your application?

The content of the `web.config` should be similar with following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- mimeMap enables IIS to serve particular file types as specified by fileExtension. -->
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    </staticContent>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />

    <!-- Web.Debug.config adds attributes to this to enable remote debugging when publishing in Debug configuration. -->
    <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js;routes\*.js;views\*.jade"/>

    <!-- Remote debugging (Azure Website with git deploy): Comment out iisnode above, and uncomment iisnode below. -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js;routes\*.js;views\*.jade"
      loggingEnabled="true"
      devErrorsEnabled="true"
      nodeProcessCommandLine="node.exe &#45;&#45;debug"/>-->

    <!-- indicates that the server.js file is a Node.js application 
    to be handled by the iisnode module -->
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="/bin/www" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />

      <!-- Remote debugging (Azure Website with git deploy): Uncomment NtvsDebugProxy handler below.
      Additionally copy Microsoft.NodejsTools.WebRole to 'bin' from the Remote Debug Proxy folder.-->
      <!--<add name="NtvsDebugProxy" path="ntvs-debug-proxy/ad81dc69-210e-42c6-80da-221ed1245211" verb="*" resourceType="Unspecified"
        type="Microsoft.NodejsTools.Debugger.WebSocketProxy, Microsoft.NodejsTools.WebRole"/>-->
    </handlers>

    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin" />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <!-- Remote debugging (Azure Website with git deploy): Uncomment the NtvsDebugProxy rule below. -->
        <!--<rule name="NtvsDebugProxy" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^ntvs-debug-proxy/.*"/>
        </rule>-->

        <rule name="app" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="iisnode.+" negate="true" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="bin\www" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any update or further concern, please feel free to let me know.

## update

It seems there are a few mistakes on your repository code. It defines the port and make the http server to listen the port several times in your code. I did some modification , and deploy to Azure for testing, now it works fine on my side.

Please try to remove or comment following code snippet, and deploy to Azure again.

- `var listener = app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port); 
  });`
  beginning at Line 18 of [bin/www](https://github.com/maggienj/Megan/blob/master/bin/www#L18)
- `var port = process.env.port || 8080; // 8080 for local or whatever number u want
  var listener = app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port); 
  });`
  beginning at Line 2 of [app.js](https://github.com/maggienj/Megan/blob/master/app.js#L2)

Comment: yes it is present in the root and added the content to the main post above.

Comment: Is it convenient of you to provide your repository for us, with which we can do a further diagnosis

Comment: the repository which I am trying to put in azure web app is github.com/maggienj/megan
( the web app runs fine as is without azure ...  it is just that it isn't working from azure site...)

Comment: Resolved! Thanks! 
Commenting the port lines helped! Thanks a lot!